# How to use Robocopy in a Powershell for loop using arrays?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, robocopy

We are migrating two shares, let's say oldShare to newShare. I have never used Robocopy before, but based on my googling it looks like it is what I should use for this task. The file directory is set up different on the shares, so I have to use several Robocopy commands, and not just one. Using my basic programming knowledge and some more googling on Powershell, this is the script I came up with to run on the new share:

```
$source_array=@("\\DC02\ArchivedData\IT-Backups", "\\DC02\Contractors", "\\DC02\DataLoad", "\\DC02\Infrastructure", "\\DC02\Support")
$destination_array=@("S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\IT\Archives", "S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\Public\Contractors", "S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\Dataload", "S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\IT\Infrastructure", "S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\Public\Support")
for ($i=0; $i -lt $source_array.length; $i++) {

    $date=(Get-Date -format dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss_tt)
    robocopy $source_array[$i] $destination_array[$i] /e /zb /copyall /r:3 /w:3 /xo /log:c:\ROBOCOPY_Logs\$date.log /V /NP

}
```

Does this look right? I just want to make sure I am not going to mess anything up big-time since I have never really used Robocopy or Powershell before.

Comment: Use `/L` switch with `robocopy` for a testing: `/L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.`

Comment: I will look at that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some syntax errors (colon in the windows filename, stuff like that), but the Powershell part was all good. Thanks for the /L suggestion.

My final script:

```
$source_array=@('\\DC02\ArchivedData\IT-Backups', '\\DC02\Contractors', '\\DC02\DataLoad', '\\DC02\Infrastructure', '\\DC02\Support')
$destination_array=@('S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\IT\Archives', 'S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\Public\Contractors', 'S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\Dataload', 'S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\IT\Infrastructure', 'S:\Shares\COMPANYNAME\Public\Support')

for ($i=0; $i -lt $source_array.length; $i++) {

    $date=(Get-Date -format mm-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss_tt)
    $filename=('robocopy_iteration' + '_' + $i + '_' + $date)

    # robocopy $source_array[$i] $destination_array[$i] /V /L /TEE /E /COPYALL /ZB /ETA /XO /R:3 /W:3 /LOG:C:\Users\USER\Desktop\$filename.log
    # /L means this is a test, it won't actually copy. Rather it will tell you what will be copied, skipped, etc. 

    robocopy $source_array[$i] $destination_array[$i] /V /TEE /E /COPYALL /ZB /ETA /XO /R:3 /W:3 /LOG:C:\Users\USER\Desktop\$filename.log

}
```